# Saving and loading filter settings in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add to shiny dashboard possibility to save and load filter settings. I imagine that user should have possibility to save many filter settings, gives them names and loads them from the list.

Does anyone know any templates or examples which can be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about any templates but you could write your own:

1. I defined inputs in the first column in the UI.
2. The default values are initialized when the session is started
3. After that you can save filter settings with the `save` button or load them with the `load` button

Other things to note:

- You could save the filter settings to file/db to enable using them between users/sessions.
- I ignored saving filters with existing names. Could overwrite it as well.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  wellPanel(
  fluidRow(
      column(4, 
             sliderInput("sepal_length", label = "Select Sepal length", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(4, 6), step = 0.2),
             sliderInput("sepal_width", label = "Select Sepal length", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(4, 6), step = 0.2)
      ),
      column(2,
             h4("Save/Load filter settings"),
             selectInput("filters", label = "Load filters", choices = NULL),
             textInput("name", ""),
             actionButton("save", label = "Save"),
             actionButton("load", label = "Load")      
      )
    ) 
  ),
  tableOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  init <- F
  rv <- reactiveValues(filters = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$save, ignoreNULL = F, {
    if(!init) {
      rv$filters <- data.frame(
        id = "default",
        sepal_length_min = input$sepal_length[1],
        sepal_length_max = input$sepal_length[2],
        sepal_width_min = input$sepal_width[1],
        sepal_width_max = input$sepal_width[2],
        stringsAsFactors = F) 
      init <<- T
    } else {

      if(input$name == "") shinyjs::alert("Filters should be named!")
      else {
        if(input$name %in% rv$filters$id) {
          shinyjs::alert(sprintf("Cannot save filter: %s already exists", input$name))
        } else {
          rv$filters <- rbind(rv$filters, c(
            id = input$name,
            sepal_length_min = input$sepal_length[1],
            sepal_length_max = input$sepal_length[2],
            sepal_width_min = input$sepal_width[1],
            sepal_width_max = input$sepal_width[2]))
        }
      }
    }

    updateTextInput(session, "name", value = "")
    updateSelectInput(session, "filters", choices = rv$filters$id)
  })

  observeEvent(input$load, {
    selected <- rv$filters %>% filter(id == input$filters)

    updateSliderInput(session, "sepal_length", value = c(selected$sepal_length_min, selected$sepal_length_max))
    updateSliderInput(session, "sepal_width", value = c(selected$sepal_width_min, selected$sepal_width_max))
  })


  output$out <- renderTable(iris %>% filter(
    between(Sepal.Length, input$sepal_length[1], input$sepal_length[2]),
    between(Sepal.Width, input$sepal_width[1], input$sepal_width[2])
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great! It's something what I need. I need to expand it a little, but now I have a base code to work on. Thanks a lot.